# display only 10% of width of item in flexbox? To define flexbox item as a relative parent with absolute children?

Tags: css, flexbox

It is possible to display only 10% of width of item in flexbox?
Is it possible to define flexbox item as a relative parent with absolute children?

```
//style
.flex { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.p10 { width : 200px; position:relative; }
.slide { width : 2000px; top:0; left:0; position:absolute;  }

//html
<div class='flex' >
   <div class='p10' > <div class='slide' >Content of 10 slides</div> </div>
   <div class='p10' > <div class='slide' >Content of 10 slides</div> </div>
   <div class='p10' > <div class='slide' >Content of 10 slides</div> </div>
</div>
```

and there is a logic to scroll the slide to certain position of 10%, 20%, etc..width of it parent p10.

I put everything in flexbox, because if i use any other positioning for outer container, automatically browser sets height=0, thus inner divs and slides are not visible on the page. I can not set the height of auter container in advance, because i do not know how much divs will be inside.

Comment: for a start, close the div's correctly

Comment: `.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.p10 {
  flex-basis: 10%;
}
`

Comment: Thank you. sorry about not closed divs.  It was just fast example, having nothing in common with real code.